# Node js to convert to json to array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stack, mean

I want to convert the json cursor which i got through the mongodb to array and send it back through callback.
Please help me.

```
enter code here

exports.byDirector = function(db, directr, callback) {

db.collection('movies').find({director:directr}).sort({"title":1}).toArray(function(error,docs){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
    }


 }); callback(null,docs); };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is outside the scope of your query. This means the callback is executed before the query has returned anything.

place the callback inside the query:

```
exports.byDirector = function(db, directr, callback) {

    db.collection('movies')
        .find({director:directr})
        .sort({"title":1})
        .toArray(function(error,docs){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                return process.exit(1);
            }
            return callback(null,docs);
        });  
};
```